# Node never begins to sync, hangs at certain point

Tags: cardano-node, node, linux

Haven't started my node for 6 months (testnet) so I cleared the container to start another sync from scratch, keep getting this weird error & the node won't start adding new `chain tips`

```bash
cardano-node.1-35-2      | [62f086c7:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:58] [2023-04-05 14:35:25.81 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Failed to start all required subscriptions
cardano-node.1-35-2      | [62f086c7:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:58] [2023-04-05 14:40:15.77 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Failed to start all required subscriptions
cardano-node.1-35-2      | [62f086c7:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:58] [2023-04-05 14:40:25.87 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Failed to start all required subscriptions
cardano-node.1-35-2      | [62f086c7:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:58] [2023-04-05 14:40:35.89 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Failed to start all required subscriptions
cardano-node.1-35-2      | [62f086c7:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:58] [2023-04-05 14:40:35.89 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Failed to start all required subscriptions
cardano-node.1-35-2      | [62f086c7:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:58] [2023-04-05 14:40:35.89 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Failed to start all required subscriptions
cardano-node.1-35-2      | [62f086c7:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:58] [2023-04-05 14:40:35.89 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Failed to start all required subscriptions
cardano-node.1-35-2      | [62f086c7:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:58] [2023-04-05 14:40:35.89 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Failed to start all required subscriptions
cardano-node.1-35-2      | [62f086c7:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:58] [2023-04-05 14:40:35.89 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Failed to start all required subscriptions
cardano-node.1-35-2      | [62f086c7:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:58] [2023-04-05 14:40:35.89 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Failed to start all required subscriptions
cardano-node.1-35-2      | [62f086c7:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:58] [2023-04-05 14:40:35.89 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Failed to start all required subscriptions
```

I start my container with `NETWORK=testnet docker compose --file node-compose.yml up` am I not supposed to use `NETWORK=testnet` anymore? This [link](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano#cardano-blockchain--nets) says there are `preview` & `pre-prod` testnets but when I use that instead of `testnet` I get an error.

What could be going wrong here? What has changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The legacy Cardano testnet has been decommissioned, you need to use `preview` or `preprod`.

Comment: I ended up upgrading my node from 1.35.2 to 1.35.7 & using preprod.